# PHP function flags, how?

Tags: php, function, bit-manipulation, flags

I'm attempting to create a function with flags as its arguments but the output is always different with what's expected :

```
define("FLAG_A", 1);  
define("FLAG_B", 4);  
define("FLAG_C", 7);  
function test_flags($flags) {  
 if($flags & FLAG_A) echo "A";  
 if($flags & FLAG_B) echo "B";  
 if($flags & FLAG_C) echo "C";   
}  
test_flags(FLAG_B | FLAG_C); # Output is always ABC, not BC
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Flags must be powers of 2 in order to bitwise-or together properly.

```
define("FLAG_A", 0x1);
define("FLAG_B", 0x2);
define("FLAG_C", 0x4);
function test_flags($flags) {
  if ($flags & FLAG_A) echo "A";
  if ($flags & FLAG_B) echo "B";
  if ($flags & FLAG_C) echo "C";
}
test_flags(FLAG_B | FLAG_C); # Now the output will be BC
```

Using hexadecimal notation for the constant values makes no difference to the behavior of the program, but is one idiomatic way of emphasizing to programmers that the values compose a [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). Another would be to use shifts: `1<<0`, `1<<1`, `1<<2`, &c.

Comment: Dude, the output expectations from Your comment isn't right. Because the output will always be otherwise - BC rather than ABC and this is a right behaviour for the program.