# What are PHP flags in function arguments?

Tags: php, function, flags

I noticed that some functions in PHP use *flags* as arguments. What makes them unique instead of plain string arguments? I'm asking since I want to use them on my own custom functions but am curious as to what the process is for doing so.

**Edit:** TO summarize, when is it best to create a custom function with flags and when is it *not*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function flags, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589573/php-function-flags-how)

Comment: Just `var_dump()` the cosntant, it'll show you the content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are just constants which map to a number, e.g. `SORT_NUMERIC` (a constant used by sorting functions) is the integer `1`.

[Check out the examples](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KX4hng) for [`json_encode()`](http://th.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

As you can see, each flag is 2<sup>n</sup>. This way, `|` can be used to specify *multiple flags*.

For example, suppose you want to use the flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` (`16` or `00010000`) and `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` (`128` or `10000000`).

The bitwise operator OR (`|`) will turn the bit on if either operand's bit is on...

```
JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
```

...is internally....

```
00010000 | 1000000
```

...which is...

```
10010000
```

You can check it with...

```
var_dump(base_convert(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, 10, 2));
// string(8) "10010000"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kp1GWG).

This is how both flags can be *set* with bitwise operators.

Comment: Also, these are called "bit flags".

Answer (score 4):

Usually flags are integers that are consecutive powers of 2, so that each has one bit set to 1 and all others to 0. This way you can pass many binary values in a single integer using bit-wise operators. See this for more (and probably more accurate) [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).