# What are PHP flags?

Tags: php, flags

I know this may sound easy for a lot of people, but I've tried to look into it (stackoverflow , php net), and I didn't find a clear answer about what **Flags are in PHP**. Maybe I didn't look it right. I would appreciate if someone could explain this, and also where they are commonly used.

Comment: What kind of flags do you mean? In what context did you come across the term? Although I'm pretty sure you mean http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: In what context are you seeing reference to PHP Flags? There are flags on the command line...

Comment: depends on the context. http://www.google.com/search?q=php+flags

Comment: I found something about flags here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635301/what-are-php-flags-in-function-arguments , but still I'm not exactly sure what do they do

Comment: That is a so called **Bitmask**. It allows you to pass multiple values (often for On/Off) with one variable. Common for option-flags. Like flag up (on) and flag down (off). See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(computing)) - Also edit your question so it is more clear what you ask about otherwise the question is not clear.

Comment: @Vodaldrien what don't you understand in the answer of the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to mention the msql_field_flags, I found this on w3schools:

The mysql_field_flags() function returns the flags of a field in a recordset.

This function gets field data from the mysql_query() function and returns a string on success, or FALSE on failure or when there are no more rows.

example:

```
mysql_field_flags(data,field_offset)
```

- *data:* Required. Specifies which data pointer to use. The data pointer is the result from the mysql_query() function
- *field_offset:* Required. Specifies which field to start returning. 0 indicates the first field

Comment: It's one thing to guess, but another to copy from w3fools.