# Multiple Flags for json_encode()

Tags: php, json

How do I use multiple flags for the php json_encode()-function?

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

This doesn't work - as just the first flag will be done an the second will be ignored.

Comment: With the binary OR operator `|`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are PHP flags in function arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9635301) (background info on how it works).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is clearly answered through examples in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You use a bitmask, as specified in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

This will add the binary values of `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` and `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` with the binary OR operator.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 16):

Those flags are [bitmasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). I wrote about it once [a long time ago here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773914/c-php-storing-settings-in-an-integer-using-bitwise-operators/2774105#2774105).

So, basically, to use more than one option, you need to *or* them together

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```