# Receive Constant or Enumeration as Argument in PHP

Tags: php

How do I make my own function to receive a possible array of "constant" as flag?

```
generateSomething($someInteger, WITH_ONE | WITH_TWO);
```

And in function definition it would be something like...

```
myFunction(???) {
  if (isset(MODE_ONE)) {
    // do something
  }

  if (isset(MODE_TWO)) {
    // do something
  }
{
```

Comment: Those flags are usually defined as values that have a certain bit set in their binary representation (so in decimal 1, 2, 4, 8, …) – that makes it possible to see if a certain flag was passed by using simple bitwise operators.

Comment: What is the best practice of doing? Define own constant in my own function definition file and require it?

Comment: Found what I want in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811922/what-does-using-a-single-pipe-in-a-function-argument-do). Thanks for telling me that it has something to do with bitwise operators.