# Use of | in PHP

Tags: php, operators

I know of || operator in php. However friend of mine experimented with single line | and got some strange results. Can anyone explain logic behind this mysterious operator? Is it just some bug or does it have a meaning?
Examples:
$a =7;
$b =4;
echo $a | $bj; Result is 7

$a =4;
$b =7;
echo $a | $bj; Result is also 7

$a =2;
$b =9;
echo $a | $b; Result is 11

Comment: It's the [Inclusive Or](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator.

Comment: The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13812082/43846) on the original post explains very well what it does. If you don't know what the pipe character is called, it is hard to search for it..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bitwise logical operator for "inclusive or". Exclusive or = "^".