# php pipe equals for number

Tags: php, pipe

Well, I know | would means 'OR' in php; however, when I was trying to make it work with number, things go weired.

You may want to try the code below:

```
<?php 
    $i = 101;
    $i |= 7;
    echo $i; // output: 103 ?! why?!
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? As aldrin stated, it's a bitwise OR, do you want a comparison OR - `$i || 7;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would convert into binary when you pass `|` to values. Please refer for more [What Does Using A Single Pipe '|' In A Function Argument Do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811922/what-does-using-a-single-pipe-in-a-function-argument-do#13812082)

Explanation:

```
Decimal             Binary
101                 1100101
7                   111
```

OR (|) operation in these values:

```
64  32  16  8  4  2  1  =   Value
1   1   0   0  1  0  1  =   101
               1  1  1  =   7
-------------------------------
1   1   0   0  1  1  1  =   103
```

Comment: You should explain here when you are answering any question instead of referring some other question/answers.

Comment: @b0s3 Thanks mate! Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Its a `bitwise OR` operator. Explanation:

Binary of `101` is: `01100101` and place values are: `64+32+4+1`

Binary of `7` is: `111` and place values are: `4+2+1`

Both values sets together will be: `64+32+4+2+1 = 103`