# what is the benefit of using Hexadecimal to define a variables in php?

Tags: php, hex

I know it looks like a dummy question, but why senior developers use hexadecimal variables as the following code:

```
//  LIST OF GENDER FLAGS
//  ***********************************
//  HEX VALUES from (0x6d)[m] and (0x66)[f] are reserved for [GENDER] FLAGS
const GENDER_MALE       = 0x6d;
const GENDER_FEMALE     = 0x66;
//  **************************************************
```

PS: I found this code in a Yii project that's why i put Php in the tags

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in general. Consider posting on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok i will do it next time, i didn't know about this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hex numbers are very easy to be changed to binary. Each hexadecimal digit represents four binary digits (bits), and the primary use of hexadecimal notation is a human-friendly representation of binary-coded values in computing and digital electronics. That is why they are used by programmers.

1 byte = 255 in dec and `0xFF` but for example

3 bytes = 16777215 in dec and  `0xFFFFFF` hex. Now you see that numbers are shorter because they have extra 6 digits(A-F).

When you define constant as hex you can get a lot of advantages. For example:

1. You can use flags [PHP function flags, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589573/php-function-flags-how)
2. Numbers in hex are easier to remember they are shorter.

**Edit**

Ad1. Flags obviously can be used with any other numeric system but hex makes them easier to understand and more readable.

Comment: point 2 doesn't make sense to me. One of the benefits of class constants is so we don't _have_ to remember the numbers/values that they hold

Comment: You can use flags defining them using a number of different notations, it doesn't have to be hex to be a flag.

Comment: Of course it doesn't need to be hex I agree but when you use hex it's easier and more readable.

Comment: In the OP's example, using the actual "m" and "f" would be *much more readable...*

Comment: i would just use `m` or `f` unless the context dictated that I do something specific. The hex values may mean something to an application that this code interacts with.

Comment: In such case it's better. Unless the software allows to be a sexual hybrid :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of taste. For one, using hexadecimal makes the constants line up nicely, and they are less typing.

Plus it looks cool.

Comment: can't even begin to tell you how much tail I've got by droppin some hex. ;)