# PHP: checking which flags have been set in user defined function

Tags: php, logical-operators

Could someone clarify how to check for flags within a user defined function.

These constants are predefined glob flags.

- GLOB_BRACE
- GLOB_MARK
- GLOB_NOSORT
- GLOB_NOCHECK
- GLOB_NOESCAPE
- GLOB_ERR
- GLOB_ONLYDIR

and I have created a new one just to test.

```
define('GLOB_CUSTOM', 123);
```

I have also tried

```
define('GLOB_CUSTOM',0b1111011);
```

The results are the same.

This function does a var_dump of the flags passed.

```
function flags_test($flags = NULL) {

    echo '$flags argument<br>';
    var_dump($flags); // int 1073746108
    echo '<br>';

    if($flags & GLOB_BRACE){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_BRACE" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_BRACE);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_MARK){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_MARK" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_MARK);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_NOSORT){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_NOSORT" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_NOSORT);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_NOCHECK){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_NOCHECK" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_NOCHECK);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_NOESCAPE){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_NOESCAPE" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_NOESCAPE);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_ERR){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_ERR" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_ERR);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_ONLYDIR){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_ONLYDIR" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    if($flags & GLOB_CUSTOM){ 
        echo 'FLAG : "GLOB_CUSTOM" is set';
        var_dump(GLOB_CUSTOM);
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Test one.

```
flags_test(GLOB_ONLYDIR); // test one
```

Results

```
$flags argument
int 168

FLAG : "GLOB_BRACE" is set
int 128

FLAG : "GLOB_MARK" is set
int 8

FLAG : "GLOB_NOSORT" is set
int 32

FLAG : "GLOB_CUSTOM" is set
int 123
```

Test two.

```
flags_test(GLOB_CUSTOM);
```

Results

```
$flags argument
int 251

FLAG : "GLOB_BRACE" is set
int 128

FLAG : "GLOB_MARK" is set
int 8

FLAG : "GLOB_NOSORT" is set
int 32

FLAG : "GLOB_NOCHECK" is set
int 16

FLAG : "GLOB_CUSTOM" is set
int 123
```

I have a few questions.

- In test one why is `GLOB_CUSTOM` showing as set ?
- In test two why is `GLOB_BRACE`,`GLOB_MARK`,`GLOB_NOSORT` and `GLOB_NOCHECK` showing as set ?
- What does the value of the `var_dump($flags)` represent(where did that number come from)?

[How to implement a bitmask in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880360/how-to-implement-a-bitmask-in-php) is where i started, i build my example from the accepted answer. Unfortunately it doesn't explain any of the points above.

Edit :

> Flags must be powers of 2 in order to bitwise-or together properly.[PHP function flags, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589573/php-function-flags-how)

This should solve the problem

```
define('GLOB_CUSTOM', 64);
```

Comment: This won't even run for me. `define('GLOB_CUSTOM', 092364023760); #PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal in php shell code on line 1`. Everything else seems as expected though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a bitmask in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880360/how-to-implement-a-bitmask-in-php)

Comment: Numbers starting with `0` are considered octal (See [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)). There is no `9` in that system (or `8`, for completeness sake), hence it's invalid. Prior to PHP7 this was silently ignored and treated as zero. See the red warning in the link. Your `GLOB_CUSTOM` is effectively `0`.

Answer (score 2):

> In test one why is GLOB_CUSTOM showing as set ?

while `GLOB_CUSTOM` is defined as 123 and `$flags` is set to 168. The masking result in

`$flags & GLOB_CUSTOM` -> 40

and because you just test `if($flags & GLOB_CUSTOM)` and not `if($flags & GLOB_CUSTOM === GLOB_CUSTOM)` your functions shows the wrong result.

you should better use a switch case.

i think this solves also the question number 2

> What does the value of the var_dump($flags) represent(where did that number come from)?

if you take the binary representation of this number, you'll see all the defined bits of your flags.